# SQL Synonym for cross database stored procedure using UDT table type

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-types

We have a stored procedure on one database using UDT(table) as input parameter.

Our requirement is to create a synonym for this stored procedure on a different database. I tried creating the synonym but it isn't working...

Other synonyms for stored procedures not involving UDT's are working fine.

Can someone please suggest a solution for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to create the same UDT on another database? What is the error message  you get? Can you pass the param via XML?

Comment: Please define "it isn't working".

Comment: @TabAlleman -  When trying to call the synonym using ado.net, it throws an exception saying "The stored procedure could not be found."

Comment: @sidux - Yes, we have tried to create the same UDT on other database but no luck.

We can pass as XML as a workaround if we dont figure out a solution to this.

Comment: do you have permissions to it? Can you execute it? EXEC ServerName.DatabaseName.Schema.Proc